# Find packages which files got deleted or missing after installation

Tags: deb, rm

I just accidentally did `rm -r /var` but luckily managed to ^C it before more damages were done. Is there way to find out all packages which files got deleted in the location so I can reinstall them?

```
% ls -l /var
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 14 08:26 backups
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Jan  6 20:26 cache
drwxr-xr-x 70 root root 4096 Jan 14 09:26 lib
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Oct 31 17:53 lock -> /run/lock
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail 4096 Oct 17 02:59 mail
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    4 Oct 31 17:53 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Jan 10 22:06 spool
```

Answer (score 2):

The more general, simpler answer first:

Assuming the dpkg status area is intact, you can determine if any installed packages are missing registered files with something like:

```bsh
for p in $(dpkg-query -f '${Package} ' -W); do
    dpkg -L $p | grep '^/' | while read file; do
        [ -e "$file" ] || echo "$p is missing $file"
    done
done
```

To limit the checking to files under `/var`, you could just change the grep expression:

```bsh
for p in $(dpkg-query -f '${Package} ' -W); do
    dpkg -L $p | grep '^/var/' | while read file; do
        [ -e "$file" ] || echo "$p is missing $file"
    done
done
```

However, this may be of limited utility for you. Partly because most packages in Debian/Ubuntu don't ship many files directly to `/var`, and also because the dpkg status area I mentioned *lives* under `/var`, in `/var/lib/dpkg`. If anything was deleted from there, your problem gets quite a bit more complicated.

Most of the data in `/var` is "variable data"; "spool directories and files, administrative and logging data, and transient and temporary files" according to the FHS. So much of it, if not most, won't come back even if you reinstall all the packages. But by the same token, your system can probably still work pretty well without it.

The most important data in `/var` is your own data; this may be database contents, mail, crontabs, and such. Most of that will be under `/var/lib`, `/var/mail`, `/var/spool`, and `/var/local`, and `/var/opt`. If that sort of data has been deleted then you might just need to hope for good backups. Of typically less importance are the system logs in `/var/log`. If those are gone, obviously you've lost some ability to diagnose past problems, but everything should still *work*. The remaining most common directories in `/var`, (`/var/backups`, `/var/cache`, `/var/run`, `/var/lock`, `/var/tmp`; some of those may be symlinks to `/run` or elsewhere) you shouldn't need to worry about; data there should be regenerateable by the owning application.

Finally, if you haven't restarted your system or the system daemons since the accidental delete operation, some of the files that appear to be deleted may still be hanging around invisibly, held open by some process. The `lsof` tool can help you find those, and you can retrieve files like that by copying them from `/proc/$pid/fd/$fdnumber`.

Answer (score -1):

I would go in a simpler approach.

Remember that you have a mirror (a cache, actually) of all your installed packages in

```
/var/cache
```

So if you want to restore programs and configs, then just enter to the cache and reinstall the stuff in there. **Of course, this will work only if you didn't installed anything that broke your system preciously AND if you didn't deleted your apt packages cache (why would you do something like that!?)**.

If that's the case, I'll go for:

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/

sudo apt-get install *.deb
```

Again, you should do this only if your system worked OK before deleting the stuff. 
Anyway, you will find all the installed packages in that location reconfiguring your setting as in the first install (so you will get programs + configs, despite the comment below).

Comment: Not quite true. System configurations and various user actions govern what debs stay in `/var/cache/apt/archives` (see `apt-get autoclean` for example; several things can invoke that). Also, debs won't be in the archive if they were installed without APT (packages installed on a new system via debootstrap, direct `dpkg -i`, etc). Further, reinstalling the debs won't help OP find which files were deleted from `/var` or even necessarily replace those files.

Comment: I agree. Generally speaking though, it should restore the system in a previous state right? **It will reinstall and overwrite to default configs all the programs installed through apt-get** restoring those deleted, and that's it, no more, no less. Of course manually installed programs won't be affected, but since they were manually downloaded probably he has some folder where store the debs?. Again, totally agree with you. It was just a simplier, raw and basic approach without the need of running any script. Of course, it has limitations in comparison with more accurate work-arounds :)

Comment: Well, it won't even work that way, really; it is unlikely to be "all the programs installed through apt-get", since the archive has likely been cleaned since the original system install, and some of the packages in that archive might have been removed since they were installed, and also, dpkg won't restore modified conffiles unless specifically asked. Oh, and an apt archive frequently has more than one version of a package; with your method, the older version might be installed after the newer one, potentially reintroducing important bugs or vulnerabilities that were fixed in the new version.